# Flip normals on Metaballs?

Tags: modeling, meta-objects

I would like to use metaballs for interior design (cave) via backface culling.
Is there a way to flip their normals? :p

Comment: Yes..ish.. you have to Alt-C convert them to a mesh, first

Comment: Yeah... no. Thats for finalizing. I want to see "inside" while editing

Comment: You can take a peek inside your metaballs by toggling a clipping border using Alt-B?  It would be nicer to frame the part you want to hide, than the part you want to keep, IMO, but that seems to be it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply toggle off viewport backface culling?

Under the *Properties Area* (<kbd>N</kbd> Key) *Shading > Backface Culling*

[image]

Comment: It would be uncomfortably close zoomed-in, defining overall interior area (cave system).. no